# 2D stack allocated vector implementation

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, c++17

I'm looking for an implementation of a stack allocated 2d array (array of arrays) which supports O(1) reads. You can guess what I mean from the below picture. Black are filled entries, white are possible gaps from erasure.

[image]

The implementation should allow fast random access O(1) on each element but also allow insertion and erase operations which do not shift around too many elements (there might be string objects located there).

Information for each array is held in an object like this:

```
struct array
{
    iterator begin_;
    iterator end_;
    array* next_;
    array* prev_;
};
```

It contains information on where this particular array starts and the memory neighbours (prev_ and next_).

I'm looking for a proven battle hardened algorithm for insertion and erasing that I can rely on. I tried constructing a few on my own but they tend to become very complicated very quickly.

Hurdles:

- When arrays are shifted, each updated array needs to somehow receive the memo (adapt begin and end pointers).
- Array objects will be themselves located in an array. This means that with every additional data member of `struct array`, the memory requirements of the whole thing will grow by `member_size * 2d_array_size`.

I'm open for all suggestions!

Comment: Any reason you can't use std::unordered_map as first level "array"?

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yes its for an embedded system with limited memory and works directly on the network buffer. It has to be blazing fast and have a known size. The array is constructed by parsing a json by the way.

Comment: Miracles are temporarily unavailable, sorry,

Comment: So basically you have one buffer (on stack) with interesting bits of info (in the form of "arrays" in it). So you don't need a datastructure to store it, its already there (maybe you need to double buffer so you can work on one copy while the other one is overwritten). Then it is a matter of making views (string_view) or casts to structs to get the data out. Or do I again miss something?

Comment: @PepijnKramer The thing is that the data is not "already there" because it's taken in via an initializer_list. And initializer_lists are temporary objects, which means that the stack space they refer to is invalidated after the end of the full expression. I can't really just reference these invalidated objects, they have to exist within my own space.

Comment: I have trouble getting my head around your question.  But what I get so far : The buffer size for the combined arrays is fixed. But arrays grow/shrink/move inside that buffer and you still want to access elements quickly like : get second element of 3rd array? And at that position you would then potenitally start a 0 terminated string? (not a std::string). Do you know how many arrays you will have in the buffer (at most)?

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yes that's pretty much it, you can leave of the string bits, the array will only hold pointers to it (std::string_view). The user can fix the buffer size with a template parameter. But it is absolutely unknown how many arrays are crammed into the meta-array.

Comment: I have the feeling it is almost like implementing your own heap. Where if you can't fit a new array at the end you need to compact / move all the arrays already there to the front, into the empty gaps.  That way moving is defered to when you run out of buffer space. To make lookup O(1) keep a vector from index to the array structures you have. Something like that.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yes that is what I came to think of. Except that I have fewer constraints, e.g. all my array elements have the same size. This makes things much more easy but still not trivial as I came to see. I hoped someone had already implemented such an algorithm so I don't have to :)

Comment: Well at least I now understand what you try to do. Do you also mean all the elements in the meta array are the same? Or can the types differ per sub-array?
If all the elements for all the arrays are of the same type I think I can come up with an implementation.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yes they're all the same imagine the thing as one big std::array, the subarray distinction is only an overlay. I would be very interested to have a look at your solution!

Comment: Can take a day or two, but I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking of an idea, where we can segment the storage into different segments of size n. entire buffer size will be the multiple of n.
When a new array is to be initialized, we allocate a segment to it. normal array operations can be performed there. when it needs more space, it request for one more segment, and if more segment space available we allocate it to them to extend it.
In this case, Minimum length of an array cannot go below segment size n. this size n can be fine tuned as per requirement for better space efficiency and utilization.
Each segment is numbered, so we can calculate the index of an element and fetch it in O(1).

Sample program (In Python):

```py
class segment:
    def __init__(self,number):
        self.number=number

class storage:
    def __init__(self):
        self.size=100
        self.default_value=None
        self.array=[self.default_value]*self.size
        self.segment_size=5
        self.number_of_segments =len(self.array)//self.segment_size
        self.segment_map=[None]*self.number_of_segments
    def store(self,index,value):
        if index<self.size and index>=0:
            self.array[index]=value
    def get(self,index):
        return self.array[index]
    def get_next_segment(self):
        new_seg=None
        for i,seg in enumerate(self.segment_map):
            if seg == self.default_value:
                new_seg= segment(i)
                break
        self.occupy_segment(new_seg)
        self.clean_segment(new_seg)
        return new_seg
    def occupy_segment(self,seg):
        self.segment_map[seg.number]=True
    def free_segment(self,seg):
        self.segment_map[seg.number]=self.default_value
    def destroy_segment(self,seg):
        self.clean_segment(seg)
        self.free_segment(seg)
    def clean_segment(self,segment):
        if segment==None:
            return
        segment_start_index=((segment.number) * (self.segment_size)) + 0
        segment_end_index=((segment.number) * (self.segment_size)) + self.segment_size
        for i in range(segment_start_index,segment_end_index):
            self.store(i,self.default_value)


class array:
    def __init__(self,storage):
        self.storage=storage
        self.length=0
        self.segments=[]
        self.add_new_segment()
    def add_new_segment(self):
        new_segment=self.storage.get_next_segment()
        if new_segment==None:
            raise Exception("Out of storage")
        self.segments.append(new_segment)
    def is_full(self):
        return self.length!=0 and self.length%self.storage.segment_size==0
    def calculate_storage_index_of(self,index):
        segment_number=index//self.storage.segment_size
        element_position=index%self.storage.segment_size
        return self.segments[segment_number].number * self.storage.segment_size + element_position
    def add(self,value):
        if self.is_full():
            self.add_new_segment()
        last_segement=self.segments[-1]
        element_position=0
        if self.length!=0:
            element_position=(self.length%self.storage.segment_size)
        index=(last_segement.number*self.storage.segment_size)+element_position
        self.__store(index,value)
        self.length+=1
    def __store(self,index,value):
        self.storage.store(index,value)
    def update(self,index,value):
        self.__store(
            self.calculate_storage_index_of(index),
            value
            )
    def get(self,index):
        return self.storage.get(self.calculate_storage_index_of(index))
    def destroy(self):
        for seg in self.segments:
            self.storage.destroy_segment(seg)

st=storage()
array1=array(st)
array1.add(3)
```

Comment: Interesting take, thank you! As you already mentioned this approach would require the caller to fine tune the segment size to archieve the best memory usage, which I think could be very difficult in my use case. Also, the meta array can never be dynamically extend.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I did not have enough time to implement a full solution (and no time to complete it) but here is the direction I was taking (live demo : https://onlinegdb.com/sp7spV_Ui)

```
#include <cassert>
#include <array>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

namespace meta_array
{
    template<typename type_t, std::size_t N> class meta_array_t;

    // template internal class not for public use.
    namespace details
    {
        // a block contains the meta information on a subarray within the meta_array
        template<typename type_t, std::size_t N>
        class meta_array_block_t
        {
        public:
            // the iterator within a block is of the same type as that of the containing array
            using iterator_t = typename std::array<type_t, N>::iterator;

            /// <summary>
            /// 
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="parent">parent, this link is needed if blocks need to move within the parent array</param>
            /// <param name="begin">begin iterator of the block</param>
            /// <param name="end">end iterator of the block (one past last)</param>
            /// <param name="size">cached size (to not have to calculate it from iterator differences)</param>
            meta_array_block_t(meta_array_t<type_t, N>& parent, const iterator_t& begin, const iterator_t& end, std::size_t size) :
                m_parent{ parent },
                m_begin{ begin },
                m_end{ end },
                m_size{ size }
            {
            }

            // the begin and end methods allow a block to be used in a range based for loop
            iterator_t begin() const noexcept
            {
                return m_begin;
            }

            iterator_t end() const noexcept
            {
                return m_end;
            }

            // operation to shrink the size of the last free block in the meta-array
            void move_begin(std::size_t n) noexcept
            {
                assert(n <= m_size);
                m_size -= n;
                m_begin += n;
            }

            // operation to move a block n items back in the meta array
            void move_to_back(std::size_t n) noexcept
            {
                m_begin += n;
                m_end += n;
            }

            std::size_t size() const noexcept
            {
                return m_size;
            }

            // assign a new array to the sub array
            // if the new array is bigger then the array that is already there
            // then move the blocks after it toward the end of the meta-array
            template<std::size_t M>
            meta_array_block_t& operator=(const type_t(&values)[M])
            {
                // move all other sub-arrays back if the new sub-array is bigger
                // if it is smaller then adjusting the end iterator of the block is fine
                if (M > m_size) 
                {
                    m_parent.move_back(m_end, M - m_size);
                }

                m_size = M;
                // copy will do the right thing (copy from back to front) if needed 
                std::copy(std::begin(values), std::end(values), m_begin);

                m_end = m_begin + m_size;

                return *this;
            }

        private:
            meta_array_t<type_t, N>& m_parent;
            std::size_t m_index;
            iterator_t m_begin;
            iterator_t m_end;
            std::size_t m_size;
        };

    } // details

 
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //
    template<typename type_t, std::size_t N>
    class meta_array_t final
    {
    public:
        meta_array_t() :
            m_free_size{ N },
            m_size{ 0ul },
            m_last_free_block{ *this, m_buffer.begin(), m_buffer.end(), N }
        {
        }

        ~meta_array_t() = default;

        // meta_array is non copyable & non moveable
        meta_array_t(const meta_array_t&) = delete;
        meta_array_t operator=(const meta_array_t&) = delete;
        meta_array_t(meta_array_t&&) = delete;
        meta_array_t operator=(meta_array_t&&) = delete;

        // return the number of subarrays
        std::size_t array_count() const noexcept
        {
            return m_size;
        }

        // return number of items that can still be allocated
        std::size_t free_size() const noexcept
        {
            return m_free_size;
        }

        template<std::size_t M>
        std::size_t push_back(const type_t(&values)[M])
        {
            auto block = allocate(M);

            std::copy(std::begin(values), std::end(values), block.begin());
            return m_blocks.size();
        }

        auto begin()
        {
            return m_blocks.begin();
        }

        auto end()
        {
            return m_blocks.end();
        }

        auto& operator[](const std::size_t index)
        {
            assert(index < m_size);
            return m_blocks[index];
        }

    private:
        friend class details::meta_array_block_t<type_t, N>;
        void move_back(std::array<type_t,N>::iterator begin, std::size_t offset)
        {
            std::copy(begin, m_buffer.end() - offset - 1, begin + offset);

            // update block administation
            for (auto& block : m_blocks)
            {
                if (block.begin() >= begin )
                {
                    block.move_to_back(offset);
                }
            }
            
        }

        auto allocate(std::size_t size)
        {
            if ((size == 0ul) || (size > m_free_size)) throw std::bad_alloc();

            if (m_last_free_block.size() < size)
            {
                compact();
            }

            m_blocks.push_back({ *this, m_last_free_block.begin(), m_last_free_block.begin() + size, size });
            m_last_free_block.move_begin(size);
            m_free_size -= size;
            m_size++;

            return m_blocks.back();
        }

        void compact()
        {
            assert(false); // not implemented yet
            // todo when a gap is found between 2 sub-arrays (compare begin/end iterators) then move 
            // the next array to the front
            // the array after that will move to the front by the sum of the gaps ... etc...
        }

        std::array<type_t, N> m_buffer;
        std::vector<details::meta_array_block_t<type_t,N>> m_blocks;
        details::meta_array_block_t<type_t,N> m_last_free_block;
        std::size_t m_size;
        std::size_t m_free_size;
    };

} // meta_array

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#define ASSERT_TRUE(x)  assert(x); 
#define ASSERT_FALSE(x)  assert(!x); 
#define ASSERT_EQ(x,y) assert(x==y);

static constexpr std::size_t test_buffer_size = 16;

template<typename type_t, std::size_t N>
void show_arrays(meta_array::meta_array_t<type_t, N>& meta_array)
{
    std::cout << "\n--- meta_array ---\n";

    for (const auto& sub_array : meta_array)
    {
        std::cout << "sub array = ";
        auto comma = false;
        for (const auto& value : sub_array)
        {
            if (comma) std::cout << ", ";
            std::cout << value;
            comma = true;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

void test_construction()
{
    meta_array::meta_array_t<int, test_buffer_size> meta_array;
    ASSERT_EQ(meta_array.array_count(),0ul);
    ASSERT_EQ(meta_array.free_size(),test_buffer_size);
}

void test_push_back_success()
{
    meta_array::meta_array_t<int, test_buffer_size> meta_array;
    meta_array.push_back({ 1,2,3 });
    meta_array.push_back({ 14,15 });
    meta_array.push_back({ 26,27,28,29 });
    ASSERT_EQ(meta_array.array_count(),3ul); // cont
    ASSERT_EQ(meta_array.free_size(),(test_buffer_size-9ul));
}

void test_range_based_for()
{
    meta_array::meta_array_t<int, test_buffer_size> meta_array;
    meta_array.push_back({ 1,2,3 });
    meta_array.push_back({ 14,15 });
    meta_array.push_back({ 26,27,28,29 });
    show_arrays(meta_array);

}

void test_assignment()
{
    meta_array::meta_array_t<int, test_buffer_size> meta_array;
    meta_array.push_back({ 1,2,3 });
    meta_array.push_back({ 4,5,6 });
    meta_array.push_back({ 7,8,9 });

    meta_array[0] = { 11,12 };          // replace with a smaller array then what there was
    meta_array[1] = { 21,22,23,24 };    // replace with a bigger array then there was
    show_arrays(meta_array);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    test_construction();
    test_push_back_success();
    test_range_based_for();
    test_assignment();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! I like that you seperated the two concepts of the meta-array and an array block. I don't like that I still have vector there however, because I strictly want to avoid heap allocs. However, you're probably right in using std::copy to do a cache friendly shift of the rest of the array. In my implementation I'm working on I try to evaluate first if the neighbouring arrays might have capacity left and only move the arrays until the new items fit. But it involves a few jumps which might make it perform worse, I have to measure it.

Comment: The vector was just a convenient way of testing separation of block administration. You could have a fixed size array to (you can't have more blocks then items so there is an upper limit). And I assumed the sub arrays had to stay in order, but yes you could first allocate in the free space and only compact if the blocks get too fragmented to allocate.  And I didn't check yet what the generated assembly looks like (but std::copy is usually pretty optimized/vectorized)

Comment: Basically I would have liked to use something like string_view for blocks. But string_view only works for (wide) character types.  Anyway you're welcome (it was fun having a go at it). And who knows maybe you still get something out of this :)